# Every k-chromatic graph has a k-critical subgraph

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I came across this result stated as a fact in Introduction to Graph Theory by Douglas B. West. Intuitively this looks obvious but I am struggling to find an algorithm to find this. If G itself is k-critical,then we are done. If G is not k-critical, there exists at least one subgraph with $\chi(H)=k$. I think I need to delete vertices of H one by one and see if it is k-critical or not. But I am really not sure.
How do I proceed after that? Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You can proceed with $H$ in exactly the same way as you did with $G$, i.e.: Either $H$ is $k$-critical (then you are done) or not, in which case it has at least one subgraph $K \subseteq H$ with $\chi(K)=k$. Then, either $K$ is $k$-critical (then you are done) or it has a subgraph with chromatic number $k$ and so on...

Note, that this process has to stop eventually as we delete at least one vertex every time we go to a new subgraph.